# Cell Frequency Counter Excel 2007

Tags: excel

I have a large array of building names in a single column.  Is there a non VBA solution for    getting the frequency of each building name in the column next to the array of names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=countif(range,cell) and drag it down`

for instance:
`=countif($A$1:$A$50,A1)` will count how many times the text in A1 appears in A1 through A50
the dollar signs keep the range constant as you drag it down column B

You could also use a pivot table